# Binding in PrepareContainerForItemOverride method

Tags: silverlight, binding, silverlight-4.0, itemscontrol

I try to implement PrepareContainerForItemOverride method of ItemsControl. It will put items to TextBox. It works nice, but how can I binding an item to the textbox text property? One way mode works nice, but when I want two way mode, I have to know the path.

Here is my code:

```
protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
        {
            base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);

            if (element is TextBox)
            {
                //((TextBox)element).Text = (string)item;
                Binding binding = new Binding("I don't know what should i write here.");
                binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
                ((TextBox)element).SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
            }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the commented line in the code in your question is what you have before then it indicates that the type of item you are providing is `String`.  Two way binding on a string makes no sense the binding would not know where to assign the new value.

The type of items being displayed would need to be some object that has a property of type `String`, it would be the name of this proprerty that you pass to the `Binding` constructor.

That said its not clear why you would even need to sub-class ItemsControl in this way.  Why not:-

```
<ItemsControl ItemSource="{Binding SomeEnumberableOfObjectsThatHaveASomeStringProperty}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <TextBox Test="{Binding SomeString, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```